# Reset Filterrific Filters on Page Re-load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I'm using the great [filterrific](https://github.com/jhund/filterrific) plugin by ClearCove.

I want to reset the filters when a page gets re-loaded. Currently, it's keeping the last search filter saved which is confusing IMO.

Here's my controller:

```
  def index
     @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
      current_user.patients,
      params[:filterrific],
      :select_options => {
        sorted_by: Patient.options_for_sorted_by      },
    ) or return
    @patients = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])
    @templates = Template.all
    gon.root_url = root_url
  end
```

I could do this the hack-y way which would be to use Jquery to click the reset_filterrific_url which is rendered in the view. But that seems wrong. How do I clear the filters whenever page is loaded?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

filterrific params are persisted in the browser session. You can disable session persistence by adding the `persistence_id` option:

```
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
  current_user.patients,
  params[:filterrific],
  :select_options => {
    sorted_by: Patient.options_for_sorted_by      
  },
  :persistence_id => false,
) or return
```

More info at the [filterrific documentation](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/action_controller_api.html).

Comment: @Jo Hund - thank you for the amazing gem , can you please tell me how can i give the prefiltered option. like i want to pass the parameter in the link_to and based on that the page which was rendered will have the prefiltered options checked in the filterrrific filter